# Setting backgroundcolor not possible

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm filling a grid with views.
This takes some time.
During the filling, the background stays black.
When views are added, the black background goes aways accordingly.

However, I would like the grid's backgroundcolor to be White instead of Black.

No matter what I do, I just don't seem to be able to set the backgroundcolor.

I've set the NavigationPage's backgroundcolor to Color.White, and I've set the Grid's backgroundcolor to Color.White.

What else could I do to make the backgroundcolor white?

I'm not sure if the mistake is really on my side.

Here you can see what's happening:

First the grid's background is black. When views are added, the black background is overdrawn by the views.

On the right side you can see that 5 views have already loaded. 
The 6nd view has not yet loaded, so the background is still black.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Edit:

In the NavigationPage / ContentPage I have this:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
       this.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
```

In this MainPage, I have a Grid ("_BigGridAsLayout") in which a custom bottom navbar is placed. This "_BigGridAsLayout" occupies the entire page:

```
        _BigGridAsLayout = new Grid()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
        }
        (...)
        _BigGridAsLayout.Children.Add(_CellGrid,0,0);
        _BigGridAsLayout.Children.Add(_NavBar,0,1);

        this.Content = _BigGridAsLayout;
```

Then I add "clsGridCell" views to the "_CellGrid".
"clsGridCell" looks like this:

```
    public clsGridCell(eImageAlignment uImageAlignment)
    {
        this.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        BackgroundColor = Color.White;
```

Comment: You can make background color transparent using custom rendered. check this article from Jim https://github.com/jimbobbennett/JimLib.Xamarin/blob/master/JimLib.Xamarin/Controls/ExtendedViewCell.cs

Comment: If you share some code so i can grab where is problem

Comment: I changed my posting and added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the background color of the view (added in the grid ) to whatever color you want .

Comment: I accidentally set the backgroundcolor to Black somewhere in my code. Your reply actually works. :-)